# Managing endpoint security and testing approaches

Tags: java, testing, spring-security, aop

I am working on a small project that includes signing up an account, logging a user in, and request data via certain endpoints. The authentication piece is done via Spring security session Ids. The endpoints consist of publicly available endpoints (i.e. signing up, or forgot password), and some endpoints that require the user to be signed in (i.e. change password, get some content, etc).  Kind of like this:

```java
@RestController
public class FightController {

//publicly available
    @GetMapping("/public/foo")
    String methodForEveryone() { 
        return "Hi common dude";
    }

    @GetMapping("secret/bar")
    String methodForSpecialPeople() {
        return "What happens in fight controller...";
    }
}
```

Spring security then has a list of public endpoints in a static WHITE_LIST

```
private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
            //public endpoints
            "/public/foo", "swagger", "etc"
}
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .addFilterAfter(customAuthFilter(), RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                .and()
```

Tests are currently being done by hitting every endpoint and determining whether it is behaving as expected (via custom antmatchers in the WebSecurityConfigurer). Like so:

```java
package com.fight.testpackages

public class EndpointList {

    public static class PublicEndpoints implements ArgumentsProvider {
        @Override
        public Stream<? extends Arguments> provideArguments(ExtensionContext context) {
            return Stream.of(
                    Arguments.of("/public/foo"),
            );
        }
    }

    public static class PrivateEndoints implements ArgumentsProvider {
        @Override
        public Stream<? extends Arguments> provideArguments(ExtensionContext context) {
            return Stream.of(
                    Arguments.of("secret/bar"),
            );
        }
    }
```

and then managed with tests like

```
    @ParameterizedTest
    @ArgumentsSource(PrivateContentEndpoints.class)
    public void privateEndpoint_unauthorizedUser_isUnauthorizedResponse(String url) throws Exception {
        assertFalse(super.isAuthenticated(url));
    }

    @WithMockUser(roles = "USER")
    @ParameterizedTest
    @ArgumentsSource(PublicAccountManagementEndpoints.class)
    public void publicEndpoint_authorizedUser_hasAccess(String url) throws Exception {
        assertTrue(super.isAuthenticated(url));
    }
```

The issue I am trying to solve can best be described with the following scenario:

- A developer adds a new endpoint;
- They add the endpoint to list of antmatchers (if it should be public);
- And then they add the endpoint to a list of public and private endpoints that gets pulled into the tests.

The problem here is that there is no enforcement of this behaviour, and it's super easy to forget to add an endpoint to a test, or if the names of the endpoints change then the tests need to be updated.

The current setup works, but I was **wondering if there was a standard for this**? I've looked at the @PreAuthorize and @RolesAllowed, etc but they only seem to be useful for securing a method, and not making it public. I actually want the reverse (i.e. the endpoint to be private by default, and then to be marked as publicly available intentionally).

A solution that I've come up with is as follows:

- Create an annotation

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface EndpointSecurity {

    boolean isPublic() default false;
}
```

- assign annotation to method if you want to make it public

```
    @EndpointSecurity(isPublic = true)    
    @GetMapping("/public/foo")
    String methodForEveryone() { 
        return "Hi common dude";
    }
```

- Build a scanner that checks all RestController methods for the EndpointSecurity annotation and the REST mapping annotation, kind of like below.. Hopefully it's enough to get the point..

```
@DependsOn("classScanner")
public class ClassMethodScanner {

    private final List<Class<? extends Annotation>> annotationFilters;
    private List<Method> annotatedMethods;
    private final AnnotationScanner<?> classScanner;

    public <T extends Annotation> ClassMethodScanner(ClassScanner<T> classScanner) {
        this(classScanner, Collections.emptyList());
    }

    public <T extends Annotation> ClassMethodScanner(ClassScanner<T> classScanner,
                                                     List<Class<? extends Annotation>> annotations) {
        this.classScanner = classScanner;
        this.annotationFilters = annotations;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    void extractAnnotatedMethods() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        if (annotatedMethods == null) {
            annotatedMethods =
                    classScanner.getAnnotatedHandlers().stream()
                            .sequential()
                            .map(Class::getDeclaredMethods)
                            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                            .filter(this::hasExpectedAnnotations)
                            .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());
        }
    }

    private boolean hasExpectedAnnotations(Method method) {
        return
                (annotationFilters.isEmpty() && method.getAnnotations().length > 0)
                        || annotationFilters.stream().anyMatch(method::isAnnotationPresent);
    }

    //Is there a good way of making this protected?
    public List<Method> getAnnotatedMethods() {
        return annotatedMethods;
    }
}
```

- And finally produce a list of public and private endpoints that feeds into the HttpSecurity.

```
public class SecurityEndpoints {

    private List<String> publicEndpoints;
    private List<String> privateEndpoints;
    private final EndpointDetailsCollector<?> collector;

   public String[] getWhiteList() {
```

- And feeds into the EndpointList that I mentioned above.

This seems somewhat convoluted though. So was wondering what is a standard approach, or am I making too much of testing the endpoints??

Comment: Would you mind providing code, too? An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be ideal, then everybody could reproduce your problem. Plain prose can be ambiguous and also everyone who wants to test an idea about how to help you has to guess about your situation and make up her own MCVE. That does not sound like it would attract a lot of potential helpers. What do you think?

Comment: Sure, it's a fairly generic question, but I can propose my current solution to see what people think. I'll update the post as soon as possible.

Comment: Just some personal feedback for you as an SO newbie: After you updated the question is is much more comprehensive and I think you can hope to get good answers with a much higher probability than before. Thank you, you are doing yourself a favour. I myself am an AOP expert, but no Spring or even Spring Security user, so I cannot help you here (I could have helped if you had implemented any Spring AOP aspects by yourself). But there should be plenty people here who can. :-)