# Stream through methods to find Rest mapping information

Tags: java, spring, reflection, annotations, aop

I have a simple, but incredibly ugly looking method. 
The issue I am having is that I feel this can be done a million times more elegantly. In addition, I would also like to scan a method for more than one annotation, and not just the Rest endpoint declarations.

I feel this can be done through a stream of `Annotations[] (method.getDeclaredAnnotations())` and filtered by a `List<Annotation> restEndpointAnnotationsAndOtherAnnotations`, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I think it's probably a fairly fun challenge for some people. The primary issue I am getting (I think) is trying to convert `Class<? extends Annotation>` to `Annotation`, but perhaps I am missing the mark.

```java
public RestEndpoint mapToRestEndpoint(Method method) {

        String url = null;

        if (method.isAnnotationPresent(GetMapping.class)) {
            url = method.getAnnotation(GetMapping.class).value()[0];
        } else
        if (method.isAnnotationPresent(PutMapping.class)) {
            url = method.getAnnotation(PutMapping.class).value()[0];
        } else
        if (method.isAnnotationPresent(PostMapping.class)) {
            url = method.getAnnotation(PostMapping.class).value()[0];
        } else
        if (method.isAnnotationPresent(PatchMapping.class)) {
            url = method.getAnnotation(PatchMapping.class).value()[0];
        } else
        if (method.isAnnotationPresent(DeleteMapping.class)) {
            url = method.getAnnotation(DeleteMapping.class).value()[0];
        } else
        if (method.isAnnotationPresent(RequestMapping.class)) {
            url = method.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class).value()[0];
        } else return null;

        return new RestEndpoint(url, true);
    }
```

Where RestEndpoint is a simple POJO

```java
@Value
public class RestEndpoint {

    @NonNull String endpoint;
    boolean isPublic;
}
```

I can actually find where it matches the Rest mapping using streams, but I cannot then apply the `.value()` method to it (since it doesn't know what annotation it is, and would be just as tedious to then cast to multiple annotation types)

EDIT:
This is a pretty handy way of getting the information on methods if anyone is interested.

```java
ApplicationContext context = ((ContextRefreshedEvent) event).getApplicationContext();  
context.getBean(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.class).getHandlerMethods();
```

Comment: What is the point of this? Spring already internally has all this information why do this again?

Comment: The point is to scan through all annotations in RestController classes and return a list of endpoints. I'm trying to attach an annotation that declares endpoints as publicly available or not (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61350383/managing-endpoint-security-and-testing-approaches?noredirect=1#comment108582675_61350383). Your response got me to look a bit further and I found this which will definitely help a lot (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541080/how-to-get-all-endpoints-list-after-startup-spring-boot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in `getAnnotation` as it need concrete annotation class to know that it has somethings like `value()`. You can create helper method that try to invoke `value()` on given object and do other parsing.

```java
private String getUrl(Method method, Class<? extends Annotation> annotationClass){
    Annotation annotation = method.getAnnotation(annotationClass);
    String[] value;
    try {
        value = (String[])annotationClass.getMethod("value").invoke(annotation);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        return null;
    }
    return value[0];
}
```

Then use it like this:

```java
String url = Stream.of(
    GetMapping.class, PutMapping.class, PostMapping.class, PatchMapping.class, DeleteMapping.class, RequestMapping.class)
    .filter(clazz -> method.isAnnotationPresent(clazz))
    .map(clazz -> getUrl(method, clazz))
    .findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Comment: Yup, that works pretty awesomely thanks :) Querying the method on the annotation was smart!